# Python - Can I convert an object containing objects into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, object

For example -

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string
 
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = Object('hello')
```

and output should be -

```
{
    'obj' : {
        'string': 'hello'
    }
}
```

I know I can do it with for loops and __ dict __, but it becomes difficult when there are too many objects to handle.

Is there a way to do this in one or two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use the [dataclasses-json library](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-json/) and [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)
you could to something like this:

```
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass_json
@dataclasses.dataclass
class InnerClass:
    foo: int
    bar: str

   
@dataclass_json
@dataclasses.dataclass
class OuterClass:
    inner: InnerClass
```

and then you will be able to use the `to_dict` and `to_json` methods:

```
>>> obj = OuterClass(InnerClass(foo=1, bar="some string"))
>>> obj.to_dict()
{'inner': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 'some string'}}
>>> obj.to_json()
'{"inner": {"foo": 1, "bar": "some string"}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I like *dataclasses-json* approach, but here's similar approach using the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library. This is likewise a serialization framework built in top of `dataclasses`, with a few notable differences; for instance, note that we don't need to decorate or subclass the inner dataclass in this case.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class OuterClass(JSONWizard):
    inner: InnerClass


@dataclass
class InnerClass:
    foo: int
    bar: str

# serialize instance
obj = OuterClass(InnerClass(foo=1, bar="some string"))
obj.to_dict()
# {'inner': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 'some string'}}
```

You will note that output is exactly the same in this case.

### Alternate Solutions

Other option can be to use [`dataclasses.asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) to convert instance to `dict` object. Also you can use `json.dumps` and pass `default` parameter if you want to serialize instance to a JSON string directly. Both options are shown below.

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict


@dataclass
class OuterClass:
    inner: 'InnerClass'


@dataclass
class InnerClass:
    foo: int
    bar: str


obj = OuterClass(InnerClass(foo=1, bar="some string"))

# 1-- dataclasses.asdict
asdict(obj)
# {'inner': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 'some string'}}

# 2-- json.dumps with `default`. Note that result is a string!
json.dumps(obj, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
# {"inner": {"foo": 1, "bar": "some string"}}
```